FATA[0005] failed to create API: unable to run post-scaffold tasks of "base.go.kubebuilder.io/v3": exit status 2
I have tried with go version 1.22.5, 1.20.5,1.17, and sdk version:
operator-sdk version
operator-sdk version: "v1.20.0", commit: "deb3531ae20a5805b7ee30b71f13792b80bd49b1", kubernetes version: "1.23", go version: "go1.17.9", GOOS: "linux", GOARCH: "amd64"
But it gives the error again and again
FATA[0005] failed to create API: unable to run post-scaffold tasks of "base.go.kubebuilder.io/v3": exit status 2
Can anyone please help me what is the problem.


 operator-sdk create api --group webserver --version v1alpha1 --kind Nginx --resource --controller
Writing kustomize manifests for you to edit...
Writing scaffold for you to edit...
api/v1alpha1/nginx_types.go
controllers/nginx_controller.go
Update dependencies:
$ go mod tidy
Running make:
$ make generate
make: go: Permission denied
go: creating new go.mod: module tmp
Downloading sigs.k8s.io/controller-tools/cmd/controller-gen@v0.8.0
go: downloading sigs.k8s.io/controller-tools v0.8.0
go: downloading golang.org/x/tools v0.1.6-0.20210820212750-d4cc65f0b2ff
go: downloading github.com/fatih/color v1.12.0
go: downloading github.com/spf13/cobra v1.2.1
go: downloading github.com/gobuffalo/flect v0.2.3
go: downloading sigs.k8s.io/structured-merge-diff/v4 v4.1.2
go: downloading github.com/google/go-cmp v0.5.6
go: downloading github.com/inconshreveable/mousetrap v1.0.0
go: downloading github.com/mattn/go-isatty v0.0.12
go: downloading github.com/mattn/go-colorable v0.1.8
go: downloading golang.org/x/sys v0.0.0-20210831042530-f4d43177bf5e
go: downloading golang.org/x/mod v0.4.2
go: added github.com/fatih/color v1.12.0
go: added github.com/go-logr/logr v1.2.0
go: added github.com/gobuffalo/flect v0.2.3
go: added github.com/gogo/protobuf v1.3.2
go: added github.com/google/go-cmp v0.5.6
go: added github.com/google/gofuzz v1.1.0
go: added github.com/inconshreveable/mousetrap v1.0.0
go: added github.com/json-iterator/go v1.1.12
go: added github.com/mattn/go-colorable v0.1.8
go: added github.com/mattn/go-isatty v0.0.12
go: added github.com/modern-go/concurrent v0.0.0-20180306012644-bacd9c7ef1dd
go: added github.com/modern-go/reflect2 v1.0.2
go: added github.com/spf13/cobra v1.2.1
go: added github.com/spf13/pflag v1.0.5
go: added golang.org/x/mod v0.4.2
go: added golang.org/x/net v0.0.0-20210825183410-e898025ed96a
go: added golang.org/x/sys v0.0.0-20210831042530-f4d43177bf5e
go: added golang.org/x/text v0.3.7
go: added golang.org/x/tools v0.1.6-0.20210820212750-d4cc65f0b2ff
go: added golang.org/x/xerrors v0.0.0-20200804184101-5ec99f83aff1
go: added gopkg.in/inf.v0 v0.9.1
go: added gopkg.in/yaml.v2 v2.4.0
go: added gopkg.in/yaml.v3 v3.0.0-20210107192922-496545a6307b
go: added k8s.io/api v0.23.0
go: added k8s.io/apiextensions-apiserver v0.23.0
go: added k8s.io/apimachinery v0.23.0
go: added k8s.io/klog/v2 v2.30.0
go: added k8s.io/utils v0.0.0-20210930125809-cb0fa318a74b
go: added sigs.k8s.io/controller-tools v0.8.0
go: added sigs.k8s.io/json v0.0.0-20211020170558-c049b76a60c6
go: added sigs.k8s.io/structured-merge-diff/v4 v4.1.2
go: added sigs.k8s.io/yaml v1.3.0
/home/ahtasham/Cofinity-X/bin/controller-gen object:headerFile="hack/boilerplate.go.txt" paths="./..."
bash: line 1: /home/ahtasham/Cofinity-X/bin/controller-gen: No such file or directory
make: *** [Makefile:95: generate] Error 127
Error: failed to create API: unable to run post-scaffold tasks of "base.go.kubebuilder.io/v3": exit status 2
Usage:
  operator-sdk create api [flags]

Examples:
  # Create a frigates API with Group: ship, Version: v1beta1 and Kind: Frigate
  operator-sdk create api --group ship --version v1beta1 --kind Frigate

  # Edit the API Scheme
  nano api/v1beta1/frigate_types.go

  # Edit the Controller
  nano controllers/frigate/frigate_controller.go

  # Edit the Controller Test
  nano controllers/frigate/frigate_controller_test.go

  # Generate the manifests
  make manifests

  # Install CRDs into the Kubernetes cluster using kubectl apply
  make install

  # Regenerate code and run against the Kubernetes cluster configured by ~/.kube/config
  make run


Flags:
      --controller           if set, generate the controller without prompting the user (default true)
      --force                attempt to create resource even if it already exists
      --group string         resource Group
  -h, --help                 help for api
      --kind string          resource Kind
      --make make generate   if true, run make generate after generating files (default true)
      --namespaced           resource is namespaced (default true)
      --plural string        resource irregular plural form
      --resource             if set, generate the resource without prompting the user (default true)
      --version string       resource Version

Global Flags:
      --plugins strings   plugin keys to be used for this subcommand execution
      --verbose           Enable verbose logging

FATA[0002] failed to create API: unable to run post-scaffold tasks of "base.go.kubebuilder.io/v3": exit status 2



